# How do i setup persistent connections in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

i do have a website which just write and read some data from my database.
for this purpose, i decided to use prepared statements but i have no clue how i can setup this stuff once, without creating them on every call like the database connection.

lets say, you call website.com/write.php.
write.php then "require" "settings.php" to get the database connection.
This causes the connection to be initialized (as the prepared statements too) every time you call something on my website.

How do i pretend this behaviour?

Comment: You can use *connection pooling*, which may or may not be an option in your database adapter of choice. That still won't allow you to persist a prepared statement though. For that, you need to change your entire modus operandi of PHP and write a persistent worker which communicates via sockets or such. Unless you have a clear indication that this will enormously benefit your performance, it's probably not worth changing the architecture like that.

Comment: @deceze it's not only the performance, it is more the stuff of creating a prepared statement every time again. or is creating a persistent worker that much work?

Comment: Why do you think creating a prepared statement every time is a particular performance problem? (Even if you say it's not only performance, that's basically what you're saying…!?)

Comment: @deceze well i could move all my initializations away in one file

Answer (score -2):

you can use static classes for to achieve that.
You can create a class Database, in a file named `Database.php` for example. Then in that class you create a static property, for example `$connection` and a function to load that property if it's empty. Then in your file `settings.php` you just import that class and use the same connection everywhere by just calling `Database::connection->function(..)`.

However, it's not always a good practice. Maybe you don't even need persistent connection, but auto-initialization of the database connection based on some dynamic settings per user. You can store these settings in sessions and recreate connection with these settings.

Comment: Static properties don't persist across multiple requests